# Adding css framework to Meteor App

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm creating Meteor app, I would like to use one of custom css frameworks i.e. Get Shit Done or Bootflat, but there are no packages for theme in Atmosphere. 
Should I create those packages for my own or use standard approach by adding libraries using `<link>` tag?
Currently I tried second solution, but colors are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor will automatically detect CSS files. Just make sure you place them in the client folder. Organize your files according to the file load rules to get the correct hierarchy with your CSS files. Read about file loading here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

It would be nice though if you could place it in a package and keep it up to date on Atmosphere.

Comment: There is one package for bootflat, but is out of date. I can create packages for those libraries, but is it legal? What's about copyrights?

Comment: You should have a look at their license and general rules regarding the hosting of their code. I'm not particularly knowledgeable on copyright. This might be a good separate question here on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Bootflat uses the [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), which is very permissive with respect to modifications and re-use, including for commercial purposes (some other open-source licenses restrict commercial use). You're supposed to keep the copyright notice when reusing significant portions, so if I'm modifying (rather than including as a lib) I try to do something like this: https://github.com/nickbenes/nvd3/blob/master/LICENSE.md.

_Note that I'm not a lawyer and this does not constitute legal advice._

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create your own package for the theme? that way you can use it in your own project and also share it on atmosphere. Here is a nice tutorial on how to create a package and use it locally as well as push it to atmosphere. [Meteor package tutorial @meteorchef](http://themeteorchef.com/recipes/writing-a-package/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I wrote above, I don't know if creating package with someone else work is legal or correct.

Comment: While it is always nice to ask the author of the code you wish to wrap for another framework, if the code is licensed for free/unlimited commercial and personal use, then there would be no problem doing this as it would be the same as forking the repo and building on top of it.